# How do I copy folders in Workspace to another workspace/different instance of talend?

Tags: project, talend, workspace

I copied my workspace (jobs/folders from an old PC) down to a shared drive, and copied them into my workspace on my new pc - but they are not showing up when I open talend as a Project? How do I  import them?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to import your jobs is

Open talend on old server.
right click on your folder under which all your jobs exist
Select Export items
Select archive file. Name it. Select Export Dependencies. --> Finish. 
Transfer this zip file to shared drive. 
Through shared drive transfer to new server.
On new server open talend and Import project from archive file.